# I'm trying to do something if users have some role discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a bot for whitelisting people but I can't check if users that called the command has a role for whitelisting people I tried:

```
@bot.command()
async def idk(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id='892437125293813790')
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        print('y')
    else:
        print(ctx.author.roles)
        print('n')
```

bot its returns n everytime so I tried many different ways but this was the best I found so... I need help

Comment: Not your issue but `guild` has a [`get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role) method.

Comment: The ID has to be copy & pasted how it is. You do `' '` just for `name=`. Removing `' '` and just pasting in the ID should do the trick.

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Thank u so much it works . Respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at line 3 in your code, the IDs in Discord.py are always `int` type.
Try this:

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=892437125293813790)
```

Then, there's a better way to do this:

```
role = ctx.guild.get_role(892437125293813790)
```